# md5sum check fails for every iso download and errno5 error during install everytime

Tags: partitioning, iso

I have a toshiba satellite e55-a5114 laptop that had win8 on it and after a failed install of ubuntu 14.04 desktop amd64 from usb the machine no longer will boot to win8 or allow install of 14.04 desktop amd64. I thought that maybe the ISO file was bad so I used MD5SUM to check it and the hash did not match. Every ISO file that I have downloaded has failed to match the hash. I downloaded from Ubuntu site as well as torrent sites, all ISO files failed to match. I even tried Zorin 9.1 amd64 desktop and it failed the hash check too.

HERE IS THE WEIRD PART----every one of those ISO files does allow me to create a working bootable USB when I use Unebootin, allowing me to run Ubuntu from the USB without installing it. From here I can go to the HDD and partition/format the primary hdd drive etc... So the HDD seems to be okay. However if I try the install option to "erase disk and install Ubuntu" or any option other than "try Ubuntu without installing" it fails every time at about the same place with an I/O errno5 error.

So I need to know if the hash mismatches are the issue or if the HDD needs to be partitioned and formatted in a very specific way or if some other issue needs to be resolved. HELP UBUNTU NEWBIE PLEASE!

Answer (score 2):

It is very possible that you have defective RAM on that machine. The behaviour of faulty desktop RAM in unexplainable. 
You should download any linux image with memtest86+ on it and run the test.

Comment: Your answer is unclear. Are you indicating the machine that I used to download the iso, run md5sum against the iso and create the bootable usb thumb drive with unebootin has potential RAM problems OR are you indicating that the Toshiba I am trying to install Ubuntu on has potential memory issues? Please clarify and thanks in advance.

Comment: Your Toshiba. Better check it.

Comment: Returns "cannot load ramdisk with an old kernel image"

Comment: To see TEST MEMORY option at bootup BIOS had to be set to CSM instead of UEFI and secure boot disabled. Selecting Test Memory returns "cannot load ramdisk with an old kernel image" when booting from USB drive on the TOSHIBA machine. However when booting from USB thumb drive using the UBUNTU machine used to create the bootable USB thumb drive the Test Memory option runs the test with no issues. Why do ISO from multiple sources return MD5sum hash mismatches? Yet these ISO create live USB thumb drives that run Ubuntu fine but will not install it to Toshiba HDD? Please Help.

Answer (score 2):

The USB live was no good because every downloaded ISO was no good due to defective RAM in the machine used to download the ISO and create the live USB. After downloading a new ISO on a different machine and creating the live USB on that machine I was able to install Ubuntu to HDD on the broken Toshiba. I Learned an important lesson about MD5sum hash check being very important.Even though the corrupted ISO would boot linux and run well from USB it would not install to HDD because it was a corrupted file.